# Why are 4 of my badges gone & Why are points not being logged?

Tags: discussion

1. An hour ago and for the whole day, I had 11 badges. Now it says 7 badges...?
2. The points are off, too. Is there a webpage explaining points. The site is showing points added that don't get added to the number next to the logo.

Comment: Is this what you are seeing?  [Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221220)

Answer (score 3):

I believe your source of confusion is conflating your Biblical Hermeneutics account (where you have 11 badges) and your Christianity account. The points feed will show your points accruals on both accounts, but they have separate totals.

Here are the [privileges for different point values](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). With regard to the points you earn that is explained on the [tour page](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/tour).  Your points should add up when you take both sites in to account.  If they don't, perhaps you could be more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks -that answers one of my questions! The points seem off, though. Is there a page that explains how the points work? Thank you, bruised reed :o)

Comment: Its actually both - the first sentence answers 1 & the second sentence answers 2.  Did you want me to try and explain the second one more clearly? There is a page that explains how points relate to privileges, but all you need to realise with regard to your confusion is that the acheivement feed is for the whole SE network, not just one site at a time.

Comment: hi bruised reed ...Ok, I get that there's two separate accounts (it was showing the same for the day -both accounts/websites had the exact points and badges (now it's different). What I'm curious about is: The points aren't adding up. Is there a webpage on this site that explains how the points work

Comment: I'll start photographing the pages. Thanks

Comment: @Daisy My advice is don't waste your time taking screen shots as the SE reputation calculations are known to work for hundreds of thousands of users every day across the network of over a hundred sites. All you need to do is read up on how its supposed to work so you know what to expect. Each of your profiles has a detailed day by day history of all changes to your reputation number.

Comment: @Caleb Unless it's [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221220) which I've personally seen multiple times and SE staff has still not addressed.

Comment: Fredsbend, I think it is a bug but it doesn't look like that bug. Caleb, Like I said, it's not working correctly all the time. At some point, the page will fix. So yes, I will photograph the pages when it's not working so you guys can see what I'm saying. That takes less than one second to do so it's not about wasting my time.